# Refer columns names from a hive table and resolve those values from another table

Tags: sql, hive, bigdata, formula, hql

I have a table with customer's bank balances (All converted to USD) from different countries in a hive table as below.

| Customer | US_BANK_BAL | CANADA_BANK_BAL | INDIA_BANK_BAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 10000 | 500 | 200 |
| XYZ | 3000 | 300 | 100 |
| PQR | 2000 | 0 | 700 |

There is a reference table to calculate different type of balances as below.

| Derived Balance | Operand | balance_1 | balance_2 | balance 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NOR_AMER_BALANCE | Addition | US_BANK_BAL | CANADA_BANK_BAL |  |
| TOTAL_BANK_BAL | Addition | US_BANK_BAL | CANADA_BANK_BAL | INDIA_BANK_BAL |

Now, I want to populate the Derived balances from table 2 by reading the balance column names and add the values accordingly and save into a new table. So, the output should look like as below.

| Customer | US_BANK_BAL | CANADA_BANK_BAL | INDIA_BANK_BAL | NOR_AMER_BALANCE | TOTAL_BANK_BAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 10000 | 500 | 200 | 10500 | 10700 |
| XYZ | 3000 | 300 | 100 | 3300 | 3400 |
| PQR | 2000 | 0 | 700 | 2000 | 2700 |

Please help me to write a SQL in hive to derive the output in table 3 by using table 1 and table 2.

And If the table 2 is remodeled to have the direct formula (like US_BANK_BAL + CANADA_BANK_BAL + INDIA_BANK_BAL) in one column, can we read this formula and apply on table 1 to get the desired output ?